# IdentityServer4 QuickstartUI WindowsAuthentication Cancel Handling

Tags: identityserver4, windows-authentication

I've configured my identityServer to work with Windows authentication and it's working fine if the user insert the right credentials, but if the user click the cancel button when the login form pop-up for the first time, he is redirected to External controller Action Challenge and i see a blank page, instead i would like to return the user to the Login action of the Account controller. If i click the cancel button after a wrong login try, the error page "401.1 - Unauthorized" is displayed.

Any one handled these cases with my same configurations? How?
Thanks to all for the replies.

Comment: Make the cancel button a simple reset button: `<input type="reset">`.

Comment: i think i have no control on that button... i don't know where the pop-up came from...i think it's related to Windows Authentication request to the browser.... if you know, please tell me :)

Comment: Ahh, I didnt realize this was the built in browser prompt. Yea, you are not going to have control over that behavior. I would convert to Forms Authentication then do your domain/windows auth in the background, which is way outside of the scope of this post.

Comment: If possible, i would like to use the Windows Authentication Integration provided by IdentityServer4... i would like only have a nice behaviour with the UI....